# How to use a Provider with 'useValue' in angular dart 2

Tags: angular, dart

I need to add an 'external' object to dependency injection in angular 2 for dart. 'External' means, it has no @Injectable annotation on it's constructor, because it's from an external library.

So i thought, i can add this dependency to angular 2 providers list in @Component annotation like this:

```
@Component(
    selector: "app-component",
    templateUrl: "app_component.html",
    directives: const [AddButton, SettingsButton],
    providers: const [const Provider(EventBus, useValue: new EventBus())]
)
```

The Problem is that this list has to be a const expression. Therefore the Provider has to be const and `new EventBus()' is not supported through being a non-const expression.

Searching the docs didn't yield a result.
How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register such classes in `pubspec.yaml` in the Angular2 transformer section:

```
transformers:
- sass
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points:
    - web/index.dart
    resolved_identifiers:
        BrowserClient: 'package:http/browser_client.dart'
        BaseClient: 'package:http/http.dart'
```

Above example shows how to make `BrowserClient` and `BaseClient` from the `http` package available to Angulars DI

You can then provide it like

```
@Component(
    selector: "app-component",
    templateUrl: "app_component.html",
    directives: const [AddButton, SettingsButton],
    providers: const [EventBus]
)
```

or

```
eventBusFactory() => new EventBus();

@Component(
    selector: "app-component",
    templateUrl: "app_component.html",
    directives: const [AddButton, SettingsButton],
    providers: const [const Provider(EventBus, useFactory: eventBusFactory)]
)
```

Comment: Ah okay :D I realized the second part with providing the value for myself in time you edited your post :D - But 'useValue' is still not working, since Dart Analyzer complains about a non-const value in const list. But at least the factory way is working. A side-question to factories: will angular create a new value with the help of the factory on each injection or will it create the value one time and serve that single value on every injection?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to edit the first part. I updated the answer. I think it should work this way as well (not tested though).

Comment: No, when i test it with simple `const [EventBus]`, it complains in chrome dev tools later, that no provider for EventBus can be found. So the only way it's working right now is with factory.

Comment: I used only `useFactory` myself for such classes.

Comment: Ah, okay! Thanks for helping! :)